# zsh: How to always execute a command after current command's execution if it matches a pattern

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, zsh

After I run any `hg` command e.g. `hg sync`, `hg rebase`, etc., I want the command `hg status` to be run automatically.

I've tried looking into the zsh hooks `precmd` and `preexec`, however I wasn't able to wait for current command's execution to get finished.

I guess this can also be achieved by automatically adding "`&& hg status`" to the command if it matches the pattern.

To restate my requirement - for any command matching a pattern, wait for its completion and then automatically run a fixed command.

Thanks!

Comment: You may have better luck with a function that overrides the command: `hg(){=hg $@ && =hg status}`. The equals expansion (`=hg`) calls the original `hg` in the path.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. This errors out on zsh. If I define this function, how will I use it?

Comment: What was the error? It works for me in `zsh`, although I did have to create a dummy for the `hg` executable since I don't have Mercurial installed. To use it, you'd enter `hg sync` or whatever, and the function would then invoke that command and `hg status`.

Comment: @Koderok: If you get an error with this solution, please edit the question, showing the new code your tried, and the error message.

Comment: You also have to think about the exit code: If you want to run a `hg status` afterwards, do you want the overall exit code to be the one of the `hg status` invocation, or the one of the original `hg` command? In the latter case, you would have to modify the solution proposed by @Gairfowl accordingly.